# Joining two complex XSLT variables into a new one

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I like to import or include two or more externals xsl's to my main xsl.

Each xsl has an dictonary

```
<my:dictonary>
    <my:entrys lang="en">
        <firstname>First Name</firstname>
        <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
    </my:entrys>
</my:dictonary>

<my:dictonary>
    <my:entrys lang="de">
        <firstname>Vorname</firstname>
        <lastname>Nachname</lastname>
    </my:entrys>
</my:dictonary>
```

Now i like to have all this in one variable

```
 <my:dictonary>
    <my:entrys lang="en">
        <firstname>First Name</firstname>
        <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
    </my:entrys>
    <my:entrys lang="de">
        <firstname>Vorname</firstname>
        <lastname>Nachname</lastname>
    </my:entrys>
</my:dictonary>
```

Is this possible with xslt 1.0 without any extensions?

Thanks

T.S

Comment: Neither of those looks like an xslt document. I presume they're supposed to be XML input documents. The answer, then would be "yes, by providing a document which gives the URIs of the documents you want to merge, using the XSLT `document` function to fetch their contents, and processing each of them appropriately."

Comment: Where are the source trees? In separate documents? Where exactly do you want to put them? In a <xsl:variable>...</xsl:variable>?

Comment: @helderdarocha Yes the <my:dictonary> are in seperate XSL .
and i like to join them in my main xsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you show us are not "two complex XSLT variables" but two **XML node-sets**. You can combine them easily into a single variable, for example like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="en" select="document('file1.xml')/dictonary/entrys" />
<xsl:variable name="de" select="document('file2.xml')/dictonary/entrys" />
<xsl:variable name="common" select="$en | $de" />
```

*Note that I have removed the `my:` prefix from both source node-sets, since (a) it is not necessary and (b) you haven't provided a namespace for it.*

The resulting $common **variable** has the following content:

```
<entrys lang="en">
        <firstname>First Name</firstname>
        <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
</entrys>
<entrys lang="de">
        <firstname>Vorname</firstname>
        <lastname>Nachname</lastname>
</entrys>
```

and the data type of the content is `node-set` - so you can use it in a `<xsl:for-each>` or apply templates to it, without requiring the EXSLT node-set() function..

Comment: Just a minor comment: the XML fragment under "the following content:" makes it look as if the two <entrys> elements are siblings in the same XML tree. They aren't; they are different nodes from different documents with different parents.